# Using Python3 with Pymongo in Eclipse Pydev on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pydev, pymongo

I am currently trying to run Pydev with Pymongo on an Python3.3 Interpreter.
My problem is, I am not able to get it working :-/
First of all I installed Eclipse with Pydev.
Afterwards I tried installing pip to download my Pymongo-Module.
Problem is: it always installs pip for the default 2.7 Version.
I read that you shouldn't change the default system Interpreter (running on Lubuntu 13.04 32-Bit) so I tried to install a second Python3.3 and run it in an virtual environement, but I can't find any detailed Information on how to use everything on my specific problem.
Maybe there is someone out there, that uses a similar configuration and can help me out to get everything running (in a simple way) ?

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install packages for a specific version of Python, all you need to do is specify the version of Python you want use from the command-line; e.g. `Python2.7` or `Python3`.

**Examples**

`Python3 pip your_package`

`Python3 easy_install your_package`.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, commands like python3 pip or easy_install return file/directory not found, while the twisted command returns twisted/runner/portmap.c:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Sorry, twisted was just an example. The last part is which ever package you want to install.

Comment: If you download the package you should have a file called setup.py try running that one as `python3 setupy.py install`